# perl:using custom appender with log4perl

Tags: perl

I have a custom log4j appender that writes log messages into a JMS queue. How can I use that appender in my log4perl config file. Can anyone send me the sample code please.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log%3a%3aLog4perl) is based on log4j, and can use log4j syntax in its config files, it's a separate implementation written in Perl.  It can't use log4j appenders.  You'd have to write a Perl class with the same behavior.  Once you've done that, you can use [Log::Log4perl::JavaMap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aJavaMap) to tell Log4perl's config reader to map the Java name of your appender to the corresponding Perl class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to perl. How to write a perl class that is equivalent to my JMS appender? Is it complicated? My JMS appender is from a third party and I have the jar file. In this new perl class am I implementing the JMS Appender on my own?

Comment: I am able to use the following appender.                                                           <appender name="FileAppndr1" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"> <layout class="Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout"> <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %4r [%t] %-5p %c %t - %m%n"/> </layout> <param name="File" value="D:/test.log"/> <param name="Append" value="true"/> </appender>    But why not my own appender?

Comment: You can use `org.apache.log4j.FileAppender` because Log::Log4perl::JavaMap maps that to [Log::Dispatch::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log::Dispatch::File).  But that only works for appenders where someone has written a corresponding appender in Perl (and JavaMap knows about it).

Comment: Writing an appender to a JMS queue won't be simple, or somebody would have done it already.  The hard part will be writing to a JMS queue from Perl.  Once that's done, linking it into Log4perl should be fairly simple.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I thought it would be simple. :-(